# Select specific ASCII characters and replace in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, char, ascii

Question - Can Char() be set to a range/set of ASCII codes like 32 through 44?

I want to run a query that would do what this attempts to do.

```
SELECT REPLACE([COLUMN],CHAR(32-44,'-')
FROM TABLE
```

but I this does not work. My reason is readability/geekiness and to shorten what is either a 15 replace nest deep query or creating a new table with 15 values.

Comment: How about using [regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) ?

Comment: will look into it. Was looking at `PATINDEX` but to clarify I am trying to replace all special characters with `-` without nesting replace or making a table to reference.

Comment: `REPLACE([COLUMN],CHAR(32|33|34|35|36|...,'-')` works up to 15 values, on the 16th it breaks. On 15 results. Ran again on ~million results and it began to fail around 50

Comment: The question would be, WHAT IF it goes beyond 16.....?

Comment: read my comment update, poses new question!

Comment: Have you looked at CLR?  You can easily create an inline function that will do what you are asking.

Comment: yes, that is how I would implement this but I just wanted to see if there was anyway of making my initial question work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N/A - there are many ways to achieve the end results but it does not look possible to select a range of numbers for ASCII characters.